# 404 return, when Setup .htaccess in fuel php

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm having problem when i want to install fule php in my pc, the problem is when i'm setup .htaccess i'm get 404 page not found, i have setup modrewrite in apache it's OK.

this is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /public

    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

i'm place my code in directory htdocs/myproject.

this is path of myproject directory

```
  myproject/
  .htaccess
  fuel/
    app/
    core/
    packages/
  public/
    assets/
    index.php
  oil
```

i don't now what happen i just following [this step](http://docs.fuelphp.com/installation/instructions.html#/configuration) but i don't get the right result.

Comment: What page do you request? Do you have all your urls with `/public` prefix?

Comment: put the complete url. Do you have all your urls with `/public` prefix?

Comment: http://localhost/myproject/ that is url i want and will be redirect to public/index.php

Comment: .htacceess file is in myproject directory

Comment: I don't see any `/public` in your url. Why do you specify it in `RewriteBase`?

Comment: ".htacceess file is in myproject directory" --- uhm, where? It is not in webroot? In the tree above you've specified you have it in `myproject/public`, not in `myproject`

Comment: `.htaccess` placed not in webroot won't be used at all. Only `.htacess` located in webroot (or nested directories) will be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can solve with change htaccess like this...thanks zvaya..you help me ..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteBase /myproject/public

        RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php/$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Oh, I see now, you have `http://localhost/myproject/` path... :-S So your webroot is 2 levels upper than `public` directory. I hope you remember that article states that "As explained in point 3, for security reasons it is **strongly advised NOT to install Fuel inside your webserver's document root**."

Comment: what the best solution for this problem..i'm new in fule php

Comment: in my web root directory is htdocs/{much folder website} so i develop another site with htdocs/{folder}..it's ok for security?

Comment: No, because it's still accessible from outside. PHP is able to include files from outside of the webserver directory, which gives you the advantage that only the server can access certain files.

Comment: accessing from outside, are you mean i'm access http://localhost and will be show all project of my pc, really i have much project if my enviroment any problem in security i'm worried, how i can solve this, should i create virtual host?..please tell me because i'm use this enviroment is so long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

from the link you give

> In that case, you need an additional .htaccess file that you need to
>   place in your document root, which will redirect requests to the site
>   root to your public folder, and also modifies the rewrites to include
>   the public folder:

so you need to have a htacess file in your myproject folder

something like this in the htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: htdocs there is a `public` directory. so your rule is incorrect

Comment: I have modified my answer, you can try to put the htaccess in your project folder.

Comment: it is still wrong. `.htaccess` should be placed in `public`. Rule still doesn't make any sense

Comment: this is another .htaceess file, different from the one put in public folder

Comment: i have been solve my problem ..thanks for suggestion that is help me alot

Comment: @viyancs: put it here so everyone knows what it was