# Correct way to remove index.php in URLs

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm currently learning fuel php and I've searched a lot in google all day long and still can't find a solution on how to remove index.php in URLs. That is, instead of
localhost/project/public/index.php/hello
I only need to write:
localhost/project/public/hello
I'm currently doing the tutorial [here](http://ucf.github.io/fuelphp-crash-course/) and when I clone their repository I'm getting a 404 error not found due to there URL having no index.php. How can I do that? I'm using WAMP server.

Comment: I googled *fuelphp clean URLs* and got plenty of results.

Comment: This is more of an apache question I think. I recommend you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809570/404-return-when-setup-htaccess-in-fuel-php and http://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/troubleshooting.html#404_install

Comment: How is this question different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423256/removing-index-php-from-url-in-fuel-php (which was your own question)? Why did you create a new question, but with fewer information, and without the proper tags?

Comment: @Barta Tamás yep I deleted the old question because the configurations I did is just copied and pasted in google. I want to try to understand those configurations better to fix my problem, but I still can't understand them so I created a new one to ask for a guide to do it. But just this morning I uninstalled WAMP and reinstalled it, it suddenly worked using the configurations you saw in my deleted question so I'm thinking of deleting this too. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an .htaccess in the top level directory and add:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: just to make sure because I tried this before and I couldn't make it work. When you say "top level directory" is it C:\wamp\www? or C:\wamp\www\myproject?

Comment: Depends, if your site, example.com is pointing to C:\wamp\www\myproject then it should go inside C:\wamp\www\myproject; however to make sure the .htaccess file is being used, you should throw a rand character in at the top of the file.  This SHOULD give you a 500 error which means your .htaccess file is indeed being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this .htaccess file to your web directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: just to make sure because I tried this before and I couldn't make it work. When you say "web directory" is it C:\wamp\www? or C:\wamp\www\myproject?

Comment: I don't know fuel, but it schould be inside 'public'  directory.